# Не работают стили в компонентах Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, webpack

На серверной части проекта используется фреймворк Flask. На клиентской части используется шаблонизатор jinja2. Появилась необходимость использовать дополнительно Vue.js c Webpack соответственно.

Для объединения технологий был найдено решение - плагин Manifest-revision-webpack-plugin. Дошло до использования компонентов Vue. HTML компонентов отображается, js работает, но не работают стили. Они не попадают в исходный код.
При этом Webpack собирает проект без ошибок и предупреждений. В браузере также никаких ошибок.

Перечитав всю информацию про Manifest-revision-webpack-plugin от автора, описание данной проблемы не было найдено. Не представляю, что делать и в чем может быть проблема?

PS1. Не работает ни css, ни SASS в компонентах Vue.
PS2. Привожу урезанные webpack.congig.js и package.json, оставив главное.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const ManifestRevisionPlugin = require('manifest-revision-webpack-plugin');
const {VueLoaderPlugin} = require('vue-loader');

const PATHS = {
    build: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
    assets: path.join(__dirname, '../assets'),
    templates: path.join(__dirname, '../templates'),
    config: path.join(__dirname, '../config')
}


module.exports = {
    externals:{
    paths: PATHS
  },
    entry: {
        index_js: [
            PATHS.assets + '/scripts/index.js'
        ],
        index_css: [
            PATHS.assets + '/styles/index.scss'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path:  PATHS.build + '/public',
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
              test: /\.vue$/,
              loader: 'vue-loader',
              options: {
                loader:{
                  scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
                }
              }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use:[
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true, config: { path: PATHS.config +'/postscc.config.js' }}
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use:[
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: { sourceMap: true, config: { path: PATHS.config +'/postscc.config.js' }}
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin (PATHS.assets + '/styles/[name].[contenthash].css'),
        new ManifestRevisionPlugin(path.join(PATHS.build, 'manifest.json'), {
            rootAssetPath: PATHS.assets,
            ignorePaths: ['/styles', '/scripts'],
            extensionsRegex: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i
        })
    ]
};
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 3 version"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.6.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "css-mqpacker": "^7.0.0",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "manifest-revision-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.1",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Test from '../../templates/components/Test.vue'

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: h => h(Test)
})
```

Test.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello {{ msg }}</h1>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
         data() {
           return {
             msg: 'world!'
             }
         }
  }
</script>

<style>
  h1{
    background: green;
  }
</style>
```

index.jinja2

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">
<head>
  <title>Test application</title>
  {{ stylesheet_tag('app_css') | safe }}
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
{{ javascript_tag('app_js') | safe }}
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT1**
[image: Итоговый html]

**EDIT2**

Если заменить MiniCssExtractPlugin на ExtractTextPlugin, то стили в компонентах работают, но файл со стилями не создается и в html не прикрепляется.

webpack.config.js

```
  {
             test: /\.css$/,
             use: [
                 'vue-style-loader',
                 'css-loader'
             ]
         },
         {
             test: /\.scss$/,
             use: [
                 'vue-style-loader',
                 'css-loader',
                 'sass-loader'
             ],
         },
         {
             test: /\.sass$/,
             use: [
                 'vue-style-loader',
                 'css-loader',
                 'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
             ],
         },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
                options: {
                    loaders: {
                        'scss': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader'
                        ],
                        'sass': [
                            'vue-style-loader',
                            'css-loader',
                            'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
...
new ExtractTextPlugin (PATHS.assets + '/styles/[name].[chunkhash].css')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там где `stylesheet_tag` в итоге что-то рендерится? Оно корректное и ведет по существующему пути?

Comment: Да, там подгружаются нормально файлы со стилями, которые описываются отдельно. Но стили из компонентов Vue туда не попадают.

Comment: покажите скрин итогового html

Comment: Могу предположить что стили попадут в отдельный файлы и корректно подгрузятся ежели во  vue-loader добавить соответствующую настройку... однако это только предположение. 
https://vue-loader-v14.vuejs.org/ru/configurations/extract-css.html

Comment: А разве ExtractTextPlugin не используется в webpack3 и ранее?  Для webpack4 необходим вместо него MiniCssExtractPlugin, нет? Выполнение действий по ссылке не дало результата при том, что у меня работали оба плагина.